# Good C++ alternative to MATLAB's "fminunc"?

Tags: c++, matlab, minimize, dlib

I am trying to convert some code written in MATLAB to C++. I'm having some (or actually quite a lot of) trouble finding an alternative to the "fminunc" function which is used in the MATLAB code that I can replace and use in the C++ code. I've been looking at the "dlib"-library because I've heard it could be a function there I can use, but I'm not sure what function to use.

This is how the "fminunc" is used in the MATLAB code I want to convert:

```
[theta, cost] = ...
fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

Does anyone know any good optimizing functions like this in C++?

Comment: "Numerical recipes in C" ?

Comment: Neural network, by any chance? You don't want to simply find an equivalent to `fminunc` - that has too many options. You want to find an equivalent to `fminunc` over just your problem domain.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is Google's [Ceres Solver](http://ceres-solver.org), an open source C++ library for modeling and solving large, complicated optimization problems.  The code is designed to handle two classes of problems:

1. Non-linear Least Squares problems with bounds constraints.
2. General unconstrained optimization problems.

Automatic Differentiation is also supported.

Several cool example applications can be found [here](http://procrastineering.blogspot.com/2012/05/today-sameer-agarwal-and-keir-mierle-as.html).

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of optimizers in dlib, some that use gradients and others than just work on black-box functions.  You can see some examples here http://dlib.net/optimization_ex.cpp.html and more generally here http://dlib.net/optimization.html.